# Load views based on REQUEST_URI

Tags: laravel-4

I want to create a setup where I can load views from a view folder based on the first part of the REQUEST_URI.

domain/folder1/ to load views from views/folder1 folder

domain/folder2/ to load views from views/folder2 folder

How would i set it up for it to work automatically? Can i modify the view path at a certain part of the lifecycle?

Answer (score 0):

Thats not how you should do it. The router shouldnt call the view directly (nor the user in your case). Create a controller and asign the views with its data there.